# Custom php form validation

Tags: php, jquery, html, forms, validation

I have a PHP form with different types of input fields (textbox, radio, checkbox,..) for which I used jQuery. It works fine for all input types except one of the question in my form for which the selected items(movies) by user are stored in an array. I think the image can explain better than me:

[image]

As can be seen in the image, selected movies by user are moved to the selected list(an array), while in jQuery validation, input names are "required" and therefore in this case only the value inserted in the textbox (in this case:"frozen") will be stored in database.

This is the code:

```
<form id="form2" action="page3.php" method="post">

<fieldset id = "q27"> <legend class="Q27"></legend>
<label class="question"> What are your favourite movies?<span>*</span></label>
<div class="fieldset content"> 
<p>
<div class="movienames">    
 <div class="field">
      <Input type = 'radio' id="selectType" Name ='source' value= 'byTitle'>By title
      <Input type = 'radio' id="selectType" Name ='source' value= 'byActor'>By actor
      <Input type = 'radio' id="selectType" Name ='source' value= 'byDirector'>By director
 </div>

 <div id="m_scents" class="field">
   <label style="margin-bottom:10px;" for="m_scnts"></label>
    <p>
     <input class="autofill4" type="textbox" name= "q27[]" id="q" placeholder="Enter movie, actor or director name here" />
     <input type="button" value="search" id="btnSearch" />
    </p>
 <div>    
</div>

 <div id="basket">
   <div id="basket_left">
       <h4>Selected Movies</h4>
       <img id="basket_img" src="http://brettrutecky.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/11.png" />
   </div>
   <div id="basket_right">
       <div id="basket_content">
          <span style="font-style:italic">Your list is empty</span>
       </div>
   </div>
</div>        
</p>
</div>
</fieldset>

<script type="text/javascript">    
var master_basket = new Array();
selectedMovies = {};
var selected;
var selectedVal;
var selectedDir;        
$(document).ready(function () {
      $("input[id='selectType']").change(function(){
               $("#q").val('');
               if ($(this).val() == "byTitle") {
                   //SOME LINES OF CODE....
                     .....
                } else     
                  if ($(this).val() == "byActor"){
                    // SOME LINES OF CODE

                } else 
                  if ($(this).val() == "byDirector"){  
                  //SOME LINES OF CODE
                }             
           }); 

$('#btnSearch').on('click', function (e) {           
           window.textbox = $('#q').val();
           window.searchType = $('input:radio[name=source]:checked').val();

           popupCenter("movielist.php","_blank","400","400");
  });    

});     

    function addToBasket(item) {
       master_basket.push(item);
       showBasketObjects();
    }

    function showBasketObjects() {
       $("#basket_content").empty();
       $.each(master_basket, function(k,v) {
             var name_and_year = v.movie_name;          

             $("#basket_content").append("<div class='item_list'>" + v.movie_name + "<a class='remove_link' href='" + name_and_year + "'><img width='20' src='http://i61.tinypic.com/4n9tt.png'></a></div>");
       });
 }
 </script>

 // CODE RELATED TO OTHER QUESTIONS IN THE FORM....
 //......... 
 <input class="mainForm" type="submit" name="continue" value="Save and Continue" />  

 </form>

<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://jqueryvalidation.org/files/dist/additional-methods.min.js"></script>
<script>
 $(document).ready(function() {
   $('#form2').validate({       
        rules: {
           "q27[]": {
                required: true,
            },
           //OTHER REQUIRED QUESTIONS....
        },
               errorPlacement: function(error, element) {      
           if (element.attr("type") == "radio" || element.attr("type") == "checkbox" || element.attr("name") == "q12[]") {
              error.insertAfter($(element).parents('div').prev($('question')));
           } else {
             error.insertAfter(element);             
        }
       }

    }); 
});
</script>
```

### QUESTION:

I have two problems with my code:

1. When I click on "Save and continue" button to submit this page of
   the form, for the mentioned question (the one you could see in the
   image), only the value inserted in the textbox will be stored in
   database while I need all selected movies in the list will be stored
   in separate rows in DB.
2. The textbox for this question is a hidden field that will be
   appeared only if user select one of the radio button values. So, if
   user just ignore this question and doesn't select one of radio
   button values, then he can simply submit this page and continue
   without any error message.

I would like to know if there is a way to customize jQuery validation so that I don't let users to submit this page until they didn't answer the mentioned question?? and then, how could I store the selected items by user in Database instead of textbox value?

All ideas would be highly appreciated,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To submit the basket movie items you can add a hidden input field. You would get something like this:

```
$("#basket_content").append("<div class='item_list'>" + v.movie_name + "<a class='remove_link' href='" + name_and_year + "'><img width='20' src='http://i61.tinypic.com/4n9tt.png'></a></div>");
$("#basket_content").append("<div type='hidden' name='basket_movie[]' value='"+v.movie_name+"' />");
```

Using this, there will be an array like `$_POST['basket_movie']` which contains the movie names of the movies in the basket.

If you want to prevent submitting, when the input box isn't filled you just add an action listener on form submit and count the `item_list` items. If it's 0 then don't submit. Add something like this to prevent form submitting when there are no items added to the basket:

```
    $(document).on('submit', '#form2',function(e)
    {
        if($('.item_list').length == 0)
        {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your great answer:) Just one more question: I added `alert("you did not select any movie");` to show the message to user. Do you know how could I show this error message beside the related question instead of showing it in popup ? (just like what is happening for other questions in the form) ??

Comment: Yeah sure. Try this: `$('label.question').after('Here your message');` instead of `alert("Here your message");` if you want it after the question label. And try `$('label.question').append('Here your message');` if you want to add it to the question inside the label.

Comment: Thank again. Also, I just found that the movies in the `basket_movie` were not inserted in DB.. I used `print_r($_POST);` to see if it was even posted or not.., but I found that still it is inserting textbox value into DB..this is the result `Array ( [source] => byTitle [q27] => Array ( [0] => Titanic ) [q8] => Array ( [0] => Drama [1] => Romance )` while I added "titanic_1997" and "titanic_1953"

Comment: That's odd, it should print. Does the hidden input fields exist? Are they visible if you replace `type="hidden"` with `type="text"`? They are also between the form tags right?

Comment: I replaced `div type='hidden'` with `input type='textbox'`, but still it does not print `$_POST['basket_movie']`

Comment: Ooh now i see. We made a big mistake. We create divs instead if inputs. Change `<div type='hidden' name='basket_movie[]' value='"+v.movie_name+"' />` to `<input type='hidden' name='basket_movie[]' value='"+v.movie_name+"' />`. I think that will solve your problem.

Comment: No, it didn't change anything :(

Comment: I can't see what's wrong. Can you add some items to the basket and paste your html output in a http://pastebin.com/?

Comment: yes, sure. Just I don't know if it is possible to copy part of html output in my browser developers tool? when I select and right click, I can't see any "copy" option

Comment: I just updated my question. please kindly see the image I have added (because I could not find a way to copy the html output..)

Comment: Just right click on your page and choose `View source`.

Comment: Aa! sorry, I thought u mean the html in developers tool... I pasted the code in the link you provided..here : http://pastebin.com/3bPuy2mp

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66052/discussion-between-s-pols-and-mona).

Comment: Well ! I found my mistake... I just didn't see the `});` which was related to `$.each(master_basket, function(k,v) {` after the `$("#basket_content").append("<div type='hidden' name='basket_movie[]' value='"+v.movie_name+"' />");`, now, it works :)

Comment: Yess, Thanks a lot and sorry if I disturbed you for my carelessness :)